# Unable to Add Comments in PR using GitHub Pull Requests Extension in VSCode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, pull-request

I'm using the GitHub Pull Requests extension in Visual Studio Code to review pull requests. I've been assigned a PR, and I partially reviewed it about a week ago. However, today, when I tried to continue my review, I ran into an issue.Specifically, I can't add comments near the lines in the PR - The `+` button is just greyed out.
[image]

Also, whenever I try to click the "Add File Comment" button, I receive the following message:
**The cursor must be within a commenting range to add a comment.** You can see the same in the below image
[image]

I was able to comment just fine a week ago, so I'm puzzled about what might have changed or what I might be doing wrong. I tried the following:

- restarted the vs code and restarted my system
- uninstalled and reinstalled the extension
- Signed out of my GitHub account and signed in again

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?

This is the output of `Help: About`:

```
Version: 1.83.0 (user setup)
Commit: e7e037083ff4455cf320e344325dacb480062c3c
Date: 2023-10-03T16:12:16.321Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

I'm currently using the version 0.74.0 of the extension GitHub Pull Requests and Issues in VS Code